# Liferay DXP 7.2 - Check if User is on a Content Page or a Widget Page

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

is there a way to check if the user is on a Widget Page or a Content Page? Maybe some kind of variable that describes the page type, I'm looking in to the documentation but can't get any useful info around it

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do it, using the themeDisplay Object as follows:

themeDisplay.getLayout().type